# Print actual live time

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I need to print the current time within my program (Tkinter GUI application), but I'm facing an issue where it will only print the time I ran the script, and not update to the current time. So, for example, I need a Start time and End time, but both end up being the timestamp of when I ran the script. Here is what I am using currently. Is it possible to update the variables to show the current time without restarting the script?

```
now = datetime.now()
now2 = datetime.now()
current_time = ""
current_time2 = ""

current_time += now.strftime("%H:%M %p")
StartTime = current_time

current_time2 += now2.strftime("%H:%M %p")
EndTime = current_time2
```

Comment: Use `after()` to update the time periodically.

Answer (score 1):

It was so many times - you have to use `after()` to run periodically function which will update it

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

# --- functions ---

def update_time():
    label['text'] = time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d  %H:%M:%S')

    # run update_time again after 1000ms (1s)
    root.after(1000, update_time) # function's name without `()`

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

# run update_time first time
update_time()

# start program
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay so, this works. But, I cannot figure out how to implement it into my script. I need to set my StartTime and EndTime using two separate buttons, and then make two labels stating "Start time: " and "End Time: " Any suggestions? Thank you for your help btw! :D

Comment: it shows how important is to put all information in question. You didn't mention buttons in question so you didn't get them in answer. I suggest to create new question on new page and better describe problem ;)

Comment: you can also use Google to search answer - there was many questions with Buttons - like `Button( ..., command=update_time)` (and you don't need `after`)